# How do I get the following program to print Last name, first name middle name?

Tags: string, parsing, assembly, x86-16

I have the following program that reads in from the user name the person first name, middle name, and last name. Then it prints out First name middle name last name, However I need it to print last name, first name middle name like the following example:

what I need:

User inputs: Jeff Dunlop Aarons

Then printed will be: Aarons, Jeff Dunlop

I know I need to start at the right end of the name and search backwards until a space is found, print it out, insert a commoa, and then go back to the start of the array and print the rest of the name but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
                include PCMAC.INC
                .model small
                .586
                .stack 100h
                .data
chars           db 80 dup(?)
AskName         db "Please Enter your full name, First Middle Last, then press enter: $"
 
numChars        dw ? 
    
                .code
                
main            proc
                _Begin
                _PutStr AskName     ;;print the msg to user for what to do
                _Putch 13, 10
                
                mov numChars, 0     ;;set number of characters to 0
                mov bx, offset chars
                mov cx, 80
;;THIS PORTION OF THE CODE WILL GET THE NAME AND STORE IT IN BX
while_1:        _GetCh              ;; get the given characer
                cmp al, 13       ;; compare the user's input to enter???
                je end_while1
                mov byte ptr [bx], al
                inc bx
                inc al
                dec cx
                jmp while_1
end_while1:




;; THIS PORTION IS TO PRINT THE NAME BACK OUT
                mov cx, 80
                lea bx, chars
                xor si, si
for_1:              
                mov dl, [bx + si]
                _Putch
                inc si
                dec cx
                jnz for_1

end_for1:
                _Exit 0
main            endp
                end main
```

Comment: When you're stuck, separate the task to subtasks **GetName, ParseName, PrintName, Exit**. Declare four `dw` variables with pointers **FirstMiddleBegin, FirstMiddleEnd, LastBegin, LastEnd**, use your algorithm to fill them and finally print the normalized name using these pointers. Do not try to write entire program at once; it's better to add only one subtask and check it in debugger before you go over to the next subtask.

Comment: You could use spacebar characters (ascii code 0x20) to figure out where each piece of the name begins or ends, although names like "Billy Bob" would throw a monkey wrench into the whole program... This task is actually quite challenging!

Comment: Don't forget if you're using 13 (carriage return) as a terminator you need to advance the string pointer an extra time to skip the line feed (assuming this is Windows rather than Mac or Linux.)

Comment: What is the `inc al` in your *while_1* loop supposed to do?